# How to set default locale in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

How do I set the default locale in rails application.rb so I don't have to add unit every time I call the following?

```
number_to_currency(@course.price, unit: "£")
```

Rails guides says my locale is `:en-GB` for the UK, but the following obviously creates an error in application.rb

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en-GB
```

Answer (score 41):

The `rails-i18n` gem contains a lot of locale configurations for Rails and **en-GB** is one of them. en-GB isn't included in Rails itself.

1. Add the `rails-i18n` gem
2. Add `config.i18n.default_locale = :'en-GB'` to `application.rb`

Comment: See my answer to avoid having to add a gem dependency https://stackoverflow.com/a/58855477/451544

Comment: @Snips Of course it easy enough to add your own locale data but I would personally prefer to use something that is well established, actively maintained, created and tested by the community. Why reinvent the wheel for the sake of avoiding a small and low complexity dependency? If you're formatting prices in GB then you probably want everything else that the GB locale in rails-i18n has to offer – times, dates, British english error messages etc.

Comment: Reasonable points, though I don't consider adding a definition to en.yml as re-inventing the wheel.  My own preference is to minimise third party dependencies - I've learned to dread a Gemfile update, no matter how widely used.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :'en-GB'
```

Comment: Be sure to have `rails-i18n` in the Gemfile for this to work.

Comment: For me it was working without add `rails-i18n` gem. To solve error @raphael_turtle mentioned I added the config.i18n.available_locales = ["en-GB"]

Comment: See my answer to avoid having to add a new gem dependency. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58855477/451544

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I had to set the locale, **locally**... There is a great workaround in Rails, many string based methods can be given a `locale` option. See the chunk of code below:

```
number_to_currency(@course.price, unit: "£", locale: :"en-GB")
```

I know this could be argued as not an answer, but it would have been really helpful for me to find it here. I hope it will be for others!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the rails-i18n gem first ( https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n )
or create 'config/locales/en-GB.yml' file with 'en-GB.number.currency.format.unit: £' entry

Answer (score 0):

I avoided added another gem dependency, by adding my desired format for currency to the existing en (English) locale.

Edit the file en.yml found in config/locales, and add the following number/currency format definition (you will see an existing hello: definition),

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"

  number:
    currency:
      format:
        delimiter: ','
        format: '%u%n'
        precision: 2
        separator: '.'
        strip_insignificant_zeros: false
        unit: '£'
```

...gives £1,000.00

As an alternative,

```
  number:
    currency:
      format:
        delimiter: ''
        format: '%n %u'
        precision: 0
        separator: '.'
        strip_insignificant_zeros: false
        unit: 'GBP'
```

...gives 1000 GBP

See [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency) for more formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the next configuration in: application.rb

> config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales',
>   '*.{rb,yml}')]  config.i18n.default_locale = :de